# What command will start debian upgrade?

Tags: command-line, upgrade

I'm looking for a command that starts verbose terminal version of what can I see after clicking Upgrade in update manager:

[image: upgrade button]

What command(s) can do that?

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` is the command line equivalent. Is it verbose enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

`do-release-upgrade` is the command-line equivalent...

... but if you're upgrading from 10.10 (as the screenshot suggests), you might do best to just reinstall 12.04.5 or 14.04. You'll save a ton of bandwidth and it'll almost certainly take less time.

Comment: But I don't know how to do it... And I don't know how to back-up settings, personal data and drivers (eg. wifi, bluetooth...). I have never installed Ubuntu - I'm using it for the first time and I'm trying to upgrade it.

Comment: If you're not using kernel drivers you're going to need to re-install them anyhow. Fortunately, the newer kernels have more drivers than they used to.